# How to refresh meta data dataframe in streaming app in every 5 min?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark-sql 2.4.x version, datastax-spark-cassandra-connector for Cassandra-3.x version. Along with Kafka.

I have a scenario for some finance data coming from kafka topic, say financeDf. I need to remap some of the fields from a metaDataDf = //loaded from Cassandra table for look out. But this Cassandra table (metaDataDf) can be updated once in an hour.

In spark-sql structured streaming application how should I get latest data from Cassandra table for every one hour?

I don't want to load this data metaDataDf for each record I receive from topic i.e. financeDf.

How this should be handled?

Comment: Have you considered `Dataset.join` of a streaming dataset (kafka) and a batch dataset (cassandra)?

Answer (score 1):

You have more options how to do something like that, basically when you are googling try to focus on [spark enrichment with static data](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&hs=xsf&sxsrf=ACYBGNRmzCAlKIKzznElR32frLszJmIhPQ%3A1578515299333&ei=YzsWXvKAFMLDwQLV0JuwCQ&q=spark%20enrichment%20with%20static%20data&oq=spark%20enrichment%20with%20static%20data&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39.176581.176581..176743...5.0..0.87.245.3......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i304i39.8m-JDwAgCx4&ved=0ahUKEwiyvsHd6_TmAhXCYVAKHVXoBpYQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)
.There are already some answers on Stack overflow.

The main problem for you is data refresh. It depends on your needs and if you can sacrify some precision, respectively if you need to remap directly after change of Cassandra or not. Some possible solutions:

1. Introduce some special event in Kafka, which will be created by external system and will notify you that your Cassandra has been changed (this is fully accurate and updated immediately)
2. Introduce constant input dstream or maybe there is similar mechanism in structured streaming. Basically, it will create separate output operation, which will read Cassandra each streaming interval and update cache if it is different (of course it is not updated immediately after change, but at the nearest streaming interval).
3. I have also seen solution with window functionality, but again it is updated only after some time.

Of course, there are other possibilities, everything depends on your preference.

Comment: Option number 1 depends on external system or we can call it writer to Cassandra. I am not sure if it is in your hands, but basically you can introduce new topic in Kafka like XYZStaticDataUpdate. External system, which is updating this Cassandra can then publish event to Kafka anytime it changes Cassandra, you will read it and update cache immediately. Of course, I am not sure if writer to Cassandra is in your hands and you can add triggering event to Kafka.